# Can one get a second Master's degree in a related field (biochemistry, bioinformatics)?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, second-degree

If one has already got a Master’s degree in Biochemistry and Molecular Biology, can he/she apply to the Masters’ Program in Bioinformatics at another university in another country?

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, yes.

Previously, I worked with students on masters degree who already had other masters degree or other postgraduate qualifications.  Some even had doctorate.  Taking a second masters can be really valuable, especially if you are seeking professional development.

It would depending on the institution that you are applying to for your second masters (such as how you meet the entry requirements etc.), so you would need to check with them for advice on your specific situation.

There are two considerations you need to make, however (this is speaking from a UK context):

**Funding**

Some funding, especially in the UK, whether student loans, scholarships from private donors, government money and research grants will not cover someone who is taking a qualification of the equivalent level that they have already obtained.  Check this with the university you are applying for.

**Visa and immigration**

I am not qualified to give visa advice, however, you should know that, at least in the UK at the moment, the decision to grant you a student visa might also depend upon whether you are taking a qualification equivalent to the level of one you have already obtained.

If you're an international student and got your first masters in the UK, your chances of getting a visa to stay to do a second masters could be nil.  Speak with a visa and immigration adviser at the institution you are thinking about.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that in the Netherlands at least, the government only subsidises a first masters degree. Once you successfully obtain that, you pay the so-called institutional fee for any further master level education, which is substantially higher. See for example https://www.maastrichtuniversity.nl/support/your-studies-begin/tuition-fees/explanation-tuition-fee-rates

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Realize that you are switching emphases from the "mainstream" of biology to "informatics," a different field that is, in this case, related to biology.

Put another way, you are emphasizing the "applied," data-intensive,portion of your field, rather than the "pure," theoretical portion. Assuming that your grades are pretty good, many programs will allow you to make the "switch."

Answer (score 0):

As many have said, broadly, yes.  That said, you should have a thorough understanding about why you need to do so to advance your career, and be able to convince potential employers that it wasn't done to put off hard decisions.